# XP freeze problem

Tags: windows-xp, sleep, freeze

XP freezes after waking up from sleep. no mouse, no keyboard. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like your mouse and keyboard were stolen...

Comment: Seems it is a slow response of your computer.Restart your computer usually can fix this problems.

Answer (score 2):

Consider updating your BIOS. Possibly even updating your motherboard's chipset drivers. It may be faulty power management, most likely in the BIOS.

Comment: i'll give it a shot. built the PC for a neighbor. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are mouse and keyboard USB?   Maybe it's not so much mouse and keyboard but the USB ports not coming out of sleep?  Can you see other things running (e.g. does the clock update ... this would indicate if XP is still running or completely frozen).